# wxPython Syntax Highlighting for C

Tags: wxpython

I am currently developing an application in wxPython, one of its main parts is to accept C code through multiline TextCtrl, and it would be good if entered C code could be syntax highlighted.

Is there a way to achieve this with TextCtrl, or is there any other convenient method for achieving the same purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a standard `wxTextCtrl` for it, use the wxWidgets wrapper of the [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) syntax highlighting editor component.  With wxPython this would be [wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl-class.html).

You can set one of various syntax highlighters with this class, there is one for C/C++ too.